# MSI: Difference between MsiTrueAdminUser and AdminUser

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, admin-rights

Currently I'm investigating windows installer log files due to installation problems.

One log file contains the property:
MsiTrueAdminUser = 1

So what's the difference between AdminUser = 1 and MsiTrueAdminUser = 1? On my developer pc I only see the AdminUser = 1, but not MsiTrueAdminUser = 1. Which setting is required to get MsiTrueAdminUser = 1?

There is also another statement in the log file (with MsiTrueAdminUser = 1):
MSI_LUA: Setting MsiRunningElevated property to 1 because the install is already running elevated.

On other systems this line contains:
MSI_LUA: Setting AdminUser property to 1 because this is the client or the user has already permitted elevation

I already tried to get an answer from msdn but this property was not documented.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this property was ever documented.  I generally use the [Privileged property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I wanted to reproduce the log entries on a virtual machine. Which windows settings / group policy setting should be enabled to get MsiTrueAdminUser = 1? Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, maybe Rob Mensching will.  You might have to open a ticket with Microsoft. I've looked and looked and I can't find any doco or blogs on that property.  All of the hits are in posted installer logs.  My friend Colby Ringeisen posted some user content on MSDN on the property reference page asking what the property was but no one ever replied with an answer.  The only thing I can guess is that it's an indicator that you are the "real" built in local Administrator account that gets created when you install windows.  But I don't know that to be a fact.

Answer (score 0):

In every case, I *really* don't expect the two issues really your problem. And I have some experience. Your are not looking for the right things, I guess, you are already to deep. Abandon your "MsiTrueAdminUser" search is my recommendation.
Besides, I share the idea with Christopher.

Posting the basic problem behaviour would be probably more successful.
Are you aware of UAC and it's implications to MSI? There I would start.
For MSI it is not important, if you are the built-in "Administrator" user or not as long as you have 
started the MSI with elevated rights.

There are two common problems. They would make over 90% of all "elevation" problems, I guess.
First prob is, that it makes a difference, if you start the msi already with elevated rights or you wait until the msi dialog is asking for it. If possible, try to assure the first scenario, e.g. with a setup.exe boot strapper.

Second prob is the understanding, when msi is working with which rights. To simplify it a bit in one sentence, it uses the rights with which it was started, but between the actions InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize (this is where the real changes are done!) it uses them from the local system account, no matter with what rights it was started.
(Assumed that it is an elevated and not a per-user install)

Remember, the local system account has a slightly different right set than administrators, so probably you are looking for the wrong detail.

The two issues get really complicated, if you have to deal with custom actions. Then there is a distinct MSI knowledge necessary to find out with which rights your actions are started.
And most times there is the problem.

Generally, it is not very good style to use elevated rights in a setup at another place than in the mentioned section (InstallInitialze/InstallFinalize). If you are the setup author, I would first recommend to read about best practices.